# Method for loading a SKScene from a file without calling the init(fileNamed:"")

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, scene

As title says, is there any method that I can call to load a `SKScene` from a file (.SKS) without calling the `init(fileNamed: "...")` method?

Comment: What's wrong with `init(fileNamed: "...")`? Is there some behaviour you wanted that it doesn't have?

Comment: Actually, I can't override init(fileNamed: String) method, and I need to pass one more parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
float screenWidth  = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
float screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
GameScene *scene   = [[GameScene alloc]initWithSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, screenHeight)];
```

Keep Coding......... :)